# Laravel & Namespacing

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, resources

This is probably nitpicky, but I was wondering how the namespace for the Laravel 4.2 "Route" works (using the resource function).

So... in all the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#resource-controllers), you see this:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

However, when I go to the "Route" documentation (http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html) you can see that the function "resource", doesn't exist there. Instead, it exists under "Route**r**" (http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html).

How do I use the PHP "use" statements to specify that I'm using the resource function? The example itself is accurate and works when I call (in that it shows all the routes that I expect):

```
php artisan routes
```

How does Laravel make the Route vs. Router namespace work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel heavily uses **Facades**. They're basically classes that allow static access (`Route::resource()`) to methods that are not static at all. In the background it makes a new instance of the `Router` class and then calls the method `resource()`. You can find more information about it in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades)

If you are looking for proper auto-completion and other IDE features that rely on resolving the class, try the [laravel ide helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `Route` here is not class but it's a [facade](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades). If you look at [Facade class reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#facade-class-reference) you will see that `Route` facade is using `Illuminate\Routing\Router` router so it's the class you want

Answer (score 1):

The `Route` in `app/routes.php` is just another of [Laravel's various facades](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#facade-class-reference) and contains *rules* processed by the Laravel Routing Engine to produce the actual *routes* that will be used in your application.

To get a better understanding, I'd suggest checking out [this short guide to Laravel Architecture](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-architecture/) to understand how requests are received and processed in the framework, as well as [Rebuilding Laravel](https://rebuildinglaravel.com/) which explains how the various Laravel components are built starting from the first file that is processed.

Comment: `app/routes.php` *is* certainly not a facade. It makes use of them!

Comment: Awesome! I'll definitely look at the resources. Thanks!